# Textbox Date Rendering Truncate Leading 0 part - ajaxToolkit CalendarExtender

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a textbox in a aspx page. The value for the textbox is set in code-behind.  When I put a break-point the text value set is “06/03/2013”. But it renders as `6/3/2013` inside the textbox.

```
txtDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
//06/03/2013
```

How can I make it to render as `06/03/2013`?

**UPDATE**

Note: Even if I use CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, this issue is not resolved.

Note: I found that the issue goes off if I remove the `ajax calendar control`. Is there a way to work it correct with ajax control?

**ASP.NET Page**

```
<%@ Page Title="Recovery" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/SimplifiedMaster.Master"
AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Recovery.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyCompany.ServicesSupportSite.UI.Recovery" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>

<asp:Content ID="headContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="headContentPlaceholder" runat="server">
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="detailContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="detailContentPlaceholder" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scrRecovery" runat="server" />
<div class="recoveryValueDiv">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" CssClass="recoveryDate" Width="100px" MaxLength="10"
        TabIndex="2"></asp:TextBox>
    <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtDate"
        CssClass="calendarStyle" />
</div>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="scriptContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="bottomScriptContentPlaceholder"
runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx) to avoid culture issues and force `/` as separator:

```
txtDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/7ttjkW)

Note that `/` has a special meaning: replace me with the current culture's date separator.

[Using the InvariantCulture Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4c5zdc6a%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Set the `Format` property of `CalendarExtender`:

```
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender Format="MM/dd/yyyy" 
                              ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server"      
                              TargetControlID="txtDate"
                              CssClass="calendarStyle" />
```

REFERENCES:

1. [Calendar Extender Date Format](http://forums.asp.net/p/1231776/3289733.aspx)
2. [ASP.NET AJAX Calendar Extender – Tips and Tricks](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=149)

---

Comment: I have updated the question with ASP.Net Markup.  I found that the issue goes off if I remove the `ajax calendar control`. Is there a way to work it correct with ajax control?

Comment: Thanks. Worked fine when used `Format` for `CalendarExtender`